# Mathematical formula alignment

Tags: math-mode, align

I am trying to align my formulas and at the end of each formula I want to see number. Since I would like to explain all formulas in my report. However after making following changes, I got so many errors not only related with the file that I have worked also another files even I did not make changes. I am a bit confused. Could you please check this:

```
\begin{align}   
$processTime& = (U / calcRate_{byte/s}) + (D / calcRate_{byte/s})$ \tag{1}\\[2ex]
                $safetyTime& = (1.0 + safety)* processTime$ \tag{2}\\[2ex]
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are, I think. You don't have to add `\tag`, numbering is automatic. Also, don't add `\\`  at the end: it creates a new line and a new tag.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica} % not necessary, just personal preference
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


 \begin{align}
\text{processTime}& = (U / \text{calcRate}_\text{\,byte/s}) + (D / \text{calcRate}_\text{\,byte/s})\\[2ex]
                \text{safetyTime}& = (1.0 + \text{safety})* \text{processTime}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use something like `\newcommand*\mvar{\mathrm}` and then use `\mvar{processTime}`, `\mvar{calcRate}`, etc. Apart from that I don't know why `\\[2ex]` I think ``\\`` looks just fine. (And, ideally, may be even load `siunitx` and set it up so one could use `\si{\byte\per\second}` but that might just be an overkill.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However the tag number seen like 5.1, 5.2 . Could we avoid chapter number? Because I just want to see tag number like 1, 2, 3, etc.